# Export chart.js as image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

**My chart generation function looks like this:**

```js
createChart(db_data: string[], count: number[]) {
    const chartOptions = {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: db_data,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Chart',
            data: count,
            borderColor: '#99f0d1',
            backgroundColor: '#60b3a1',
            borderWidth: 0.1,
          },
          
        ],
      },
      onAnimationComplete: function()
      {
          this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].data, true);
      },
      options: {
...


    this.chartElement = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.chart = new Chart(this.chartElement, chartOptions);
```

I want to export this as image(png) but the trick is, that i want to modify the background and bar's colors. My export function is works well, but i cant set the modified background attributes.

```
exportChart() {
  const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  
  
  const canvas = this.chart.canvas;

  console.log(canvas);
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';


  const chartDataURL = this.chart.toBase64Image();

  
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; 

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = chartDataURL;
  link.download = `statistic_${currentDate}.png`;
  link.click();
}
```

I tried to modified the chart generation (with ctx)

Comment: I know that is complicated to generate a chart with different colors for different contexts. My approach when I have such cases is to render again the chart under a hidden div and  to use this one when I have to generate the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.4.0/configuration/canvas-background.html) if you want to download the chart with a background color you will need to use a custom plugin for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      customCanvasBackgroundColor: {
        color: 'pink'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customCanvasBackgroundColor',
    beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
      const {
        ctx
      } = chart;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
      ctx.fillStyle = options.color || '#99ffff';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js"></script>
</body>
```